# .htaccess rewrite with varying parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am new to `.htaccess` in the sense that if it isn't a like for like divert I have no experience. Regular expressions is where I tend to find things don't always go smoothly.

At the moment I have a situation like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://example.com/product.php?productA2013$ http://example.com/productA [R=301,L]
```

The problem is when I add a new productA for 2014 i need to change all my rewrites as this applies to many products eg productB, productC, productD, productE etc etc.

I need a way of identifying it without the 2013 at the end. I tried `http://example.com/product.php?productA*` but it did not seem to work. Any help with an explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can detect it using PHP. But don't you know everyone hate those restriction sites? :P

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^http://example.com/product.php?productA\d{4}$ http://example.com/productA [R=301,L]
```

Not sure if you have to escape those dots and stuff cause htaccess has proven to be some-what intelligent to me.. In case you do place `\` before all dots and slashes

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, very much appreciated. If it's not too much to ask can I ask what the end bit does. Does the `d` mean digits and the `4` mean number of?

Comment: Yep, you can also have a syntax like `\d{2,4}` which would match any number that's 2 to 4 digits long. :P

Comment: thanks @php_nub_qq, I'll get my head around rewrites one day, even if it kills me :)

Comment: Thanks, but I tried this today but it did not work. The reason being it does not select the correct product from the DB